# Convert ASP function to PHP to generate password

Tags: php, asp.net, md5

I am working on converting an ASP site to PHP. The site uses a 3rd party API. The 3rd party API requires a UserID which was stored in the database and a password for each user. The ASP site didn't save the passwords in the database, instead they used the following function to derive the password every time based on the UserID:

```
public static string GetLmsUserPassword(int userId)
{
    var hash = userId.ToString().MD5();
    return hash.Substring(15, 4) + hash.Substring(4, 4);
}
```

In PHP, I wrote the following:

```
function lms_password($user_id) {
    $hash = md5((int)$user_id);
    $password = substr($hash,15,4).substr($hash,4,4);
    return $password;
}
```

However, it appears the password generated in PHP does not match the password in ASP. I am wondering if ASP does md5 differently?

An example UserID is actually a string, not just a number: 22E21F5D-7979-467E-928D-4EFCC323BDCB

Comment: Wow, that's a terrible idea (no offense).

Comment: Start by displaying the hash returned in ASP and the one returned in PHP to see if they match? Also what does userID.ToString() returns in your ASP code if it takes an int as input ?

Comment: I just realized that the ASP function types the UserID as int. So I updated my function to do the same:

Comment: I do not have an ASP server to test this on, I know nothing about ASP - I only code in PHP. I just have access to the files and the database (which I had to convert to MySQL from SQL).

Comment: I would start by NOT using this extremely insecure function :)

Comment: Yep. Use at least sha1. md5 can be brutaforced with GPU in ~10mins.

Comment: I am not going to long term use this function, I just need to pull these passwords out of the existing system so we don't have to reset 4000+ passwords in the 3rd party API and make migration a nightmare.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to reset them anyway?  Unless you're planning on *keeping* them as MD5, which would be a very, very bad idea?

Comment: I can get the password and store it in the new database using sha1 instead of MD5. I am writing a migration script to a completely new system, not simply trying to clone the code.

Comment: Seriously, use SHA512, or bcrypt/blowfish, or something used for passwords.  SHA1 isn't good for this, either.

Comment: I will tackle encrypting the password again later, but thank you for the advice. Right now my issue is relating to how to get matching function in PHP to what was written by the previous ASP dev so I can get to that point in the first place.

Comment: `(int)"22E21F5D-7979-467E-928D-4EFCC323BDCB"` in PHP will return you 22.  How is that an `int` in ASP?  What does `userId.ToString()` return?

Comment: I am awaiting access to the client's current ASP server so I can do a test file and find out.

Comment: Turns out the PHP code I had returned the exact same thing as the ASP code. The previous SQL database was so poorly organized, the actual UserID I was supposed to use was buried in a random, non-obvious table that didn't even look like it had user info in it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in results between the .NET and PHP versions could be due to the way each casts a string to an int.  Try casting your example id in both, and compare.

Answer (score 1):

ASP: `var hash = userId.ToString().MD5();`

See that `ToString()` part? That means the ID is probably being interpreted as a string.

Your PHP: `$hash = md5((int)$user_id);`

explicitly casts it as an int, which will hash to a completely different value.

> An example UserID is actually a string, not just a number: 22E21F5D-7979-467E-928D-4EFCC323BDCB

So... why are you casting it as an int? :I

**edit:** I also like that the password appears to be statically generated from a hash of the userID. Very secure.